# Tripwire passphrase copy/paste on Debian Buster

Tags: linux, debian, tripwire

I've been using Tripwire for a while and it was working well until today.
I just upgraded to Debian Buster, now I have an issue when I copy/paste a passphrase on a SSH terminal, after a "tripwire --update -r" :

```
Please enter your local passphrase: 
Incorrect local passphrase.
```

It seems that copy/paste isn't working anymore on Debian Buster but just for Tripwire passphrase like above (it works if I type it manually).
This is the right passphrase, I tested to paste it on the terminal or anywhere else.
It only work when I enter password for the first time on Tripwire installation (site/local passphrase creation).

Tripwire version in Debian Stretch is 2.4.3.1-2+b4 and in Debian Buster is 2.4.3.7-1+b10.

Does anyone else using it has faced this issue ?

Comment: Does shift+ctrl+c and shift+ctrl+v work to copy and then paste in the terminal? Does middle click (mouse wheel) work to copy and paste? How exactly are you copying and pasting to the terminal? Please update your post with whether copying and pasting works period not just with your tripwire password.

Comment: I used to do shift+ctrl+c then shift+ctrl+v, not working anymore.
Also middle click on mouse was not working.
If I'm in classic terminal, it works.
So it's only the passphrase prompt of Tripwire.

Comment: Have you confirmed that the password is correct via manually typing it out? And by password prompt for Tripwire, what does that mean? Is it in a terminal emulator or is a graphical prompt? In what context are you being provided this? Please edit your post to have these details instead of responding to me. Thank you.

Comment: One last question, Have you confirmed what you are copying and pasting is the pass phrase?

Comment: Post has been updated with your questions, any ideas ?